# In Next 13, how can I fetch data in a server component and use results in a client component?

Tags: reactjs, vercel, next.js13

Hi Im new to next13 and still trying to get acquainted with it. Im start to understand the segregation between server and client components but some parts are still a bit unclear.

In my use case, I want to fetch data (a list) and from that data, define buttons on a page. Is the only way to do this by using an entire client component? Or is there a way to let the server component fetch the data and somehow feed that data to a client component to display on the page as buttons?

Answer (score 0):

server components can render client components. you could create a reusable `Button` client component (in large-scale applications buttons or inputs are always created in a separate reusable component) and render it inside your server component. your goal should be to maximize the server-generated components